# Dynamically creating a function that wraps member function invocation

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Here is the scenario: I'm working with a legacy library that uses function pointers for callbacks. Rewriting the legacy library is not a feasible option. But I'd also like the callbacks to invoke class member functions rather than global functions.

As far as I can tell, the best option is to hard-code a fixed number of pre-defined global functions that use global class pointers to perform the dispatch:

```
foo *globalPointers[3];
void callback1() {globalPointers[0]->invoke(); }
void callback2() {globalPointers[1]->invoke(); }
void callback3() {globalPointers[2]->invoke(); }
void (*globalCallbacks[3])() = {&callback1, &callback2, &callback3};

class foo
{
    public:
    int idx;

    foo() 
    {
        idx = findFreeSlot();
        globalPointers[idx] = this;
        registerLibraryCallback(globalCallbacks[idx]);
    }
    ~foo() {releaseSlot(idx);}

    void invoke();
};
```

Yuck yuck yuck! Is there any (portable) way of dynamically creating new callback functions at runtime, instead of hard-coding a set (in this case, 3) at compile time? In other words, is there a (compliant) way to "memcpy a function" and modify its local variables?

Of course all of these problems go away if using functional objects instead of global function pointers, etc. but again I am stuck with a legacy library.

Comment: So this library does not provide any way to supply user-defined argument into callback? It is possible to generate function sunk at runtime, however this will definitely involve more trickery than global pointer table and won't really be cross-platform.

Comment: @VTT unfortunately not...

Comment: I don't suppose this would be possible without creating something reminiscent of a scripting engine.